# Spring Boot JSON filter

Tags: json, spring-boot, filter

I am a newbie at Spring Boot. I got an issue that I need to filter JSON data from an external URL. All I searched is like:

```
 public String getAll(){
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    String resource_url = API_URL;
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange(resource_url,HttpMethod.GET,entity,String.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

, which callback a String object and I have no idea how to filter the data, like select specific data with 'name' or sort data by the number of 'like', etc.

Comment: Refer this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html

Comment: Deserialize the response body to object, then you can operate them such as filtering or sorting...

Comment: The JSON data is like `{
"posts"​: [{
"id"​: ​1​,
"author"​: ​"Rylee Paul"​,
"authorId"​: ​9​,
"likes"​: ​960​,
"popularity"​: ​0.13​,
"reads"​: ​50361​,
"tags"​: [ ​"tech"​, ​"health" ​]
},{
"id"​: ​2​,
"author"​: ​"Marry Lee"​,
"authorId"​: ​2​,
"likes"​: ​326​,
"popularity"​: ​0.06​,
"reads"​: ​20261​,
"tags"​: [ ​​"health" ​]
},
...
]
}` how do deal with it